# The limit of a function that returns an ordered set

Tags: real-analysis

I made a "pre-post" to this and the comments helped me hone in my question and clean up my notation

What is the notion of "limit" with a function that returns an ordered set of changing dimensions?

Specifically, I am looking for the notion of limit with the following type of function

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$

$f: X\to Y$, $X\subset\mathbb{R}^ {<\infty} \space \space Y\subset \mathbb{R}^ {<\infty}$

$f: x\mapsto y$

Where $x$ is some input and $y=(f_1(x), f_2(x),...f_{m(x)}(x))$ , is a tuple of some size $m(x)$

$m:X\to \mathbb{N}  $

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}m(x)= \infty$

So $y$ is a tuple of growing size the closer $x$ gets to $a$

I'm not sure if all my notation is correct but by $\mathbb{R}^ {<\infty}$ I meant the set of all finite tuples made from real numbers

A concrete example of the sort of function I mean is the function
$g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^ {<\infty} $

$g(n)=(f_1(n),f_1(n),...f_1(n))$ a tuple of size n with the same element repeated n times

What is $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(n)$ if $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_1(x)=0$

My guess would be an infinite tuple of infinitly repeated $0$s but I'm not sure if the notion of limit can even work here

Comment: This is hard to follow.  A function requires a domain and a range.  What are those for your function?  If the range is $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} R^n$ then what topology did you have in mind?

Comment: I think "ordered set" is more commonly called "sequence" or maybe "tuple".

Comment: If you can [edit] the question to show us an _actual example_  with a particular function $f$ and the limit object you expect to see we might be able to help. As written, this is too vague for an answer.

Comment: @lulu , I think $X$ has the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^\infty:=\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}$. Same with $Y$.

Comment: I think $Y= \Bbb R^{ \lt \infty}$ (the set of all finite sequences of real numbers) is the intended co-domain.

Comment: The definition will vary, depending on which topology or metric you impose upon $\Bbb R^{\infty}.$ You first need to define what $x\to a$ means.

Comment: I have added a concrete example of the type of function I mean